# Contador para dos botones

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

tengo dos botones los cuales quiero realizar un contador de incremento y el otro de disminución y que muestre el resultado en un único campo de texto.

```
  <Button ID="buttonLogin" style="widht:60px; height:50px;" Class="ButtonAction"
      onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"
      onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" runat="server">Login
  </Button><br></br>
  <Button ID="buttonLogout" style="widht:60px; height:50px;" Class="ButtonAction"
      onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"
      onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" runat="server">Logout
   </Button>


   <asp:TextBox ID="txtNpersonas" style="font-size:25px; width:150px;"   runat="server"/> 

    $("[id$=buttonLogin]").click( function(){ 

       alert("llega");

       int valor = 1++;
       $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").attr(valor);


     });
```

Por ejemplo esto es otra acción en mi sistema, el caso es que mi sistema trabaja con diferentes lenguajes de programación, coloco un ejemplo

```
protected void Button_Arranque(object sender, EventArgs e){
```

this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&ShowMenu=0&Prueba=2&sDatos=" + sDatos));
    }

En este caso solo actualizo mi pagina claro esto es en c#.
En el caso del contador necesito tomar en cuentas el valor del campo de texto que se encuentra actualmente y empezar a aumentar o disminuir dependiendo del numero, todo esto seria js. En la caso de tener una variable = 0 siempre me va a contar desde 0 sin tener en cuenta lo que haya en el campo de texto.

```
var valor = $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val();
```

Asigne esto pero no me sirve, esta mal formado. ¿Como puedo realizarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero declara una variable global:

```
var valor = 0;
```

y en cada click a cada botón, incrementa el valor según qué botón apriete:

```
$("[id$=buttonLogin]").click( function(){ 
  valor += 1; // o valor -=1 si apreta el botón "Logout"
  $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val(valor);
});
```

finalmente asignar el `.val()` del `textarea` con la variable `valor`

```
$("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val(valor);
```

En caso de que quieras asignar un valor predeterminado, deberás preguntar si hay valor en el `textarea`, y si lo hay, **multiplicalo por 1** para que `.val()` -que es **string**- se convierta en **numeric** y haga bien el conteo.

```
var valor = ($("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val()!='')?$("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val()*1:0;
```

```js
var valor = ($("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val()!='')?$("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val()*1:0;
$("[id$=buttonLogin]").click( function(){ 
  //alert("llega");
  valor += 1;
  $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val(valor);
});
$("[id$=buttonLogout]").click( function(){ 
  //alert("llega");
  valor -= 1;
  $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Button ID="buttonLogin" style="widht:60px; height:50px;" Class="ButtonAction"
      onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"
      onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" runat="server">Login
  </Button><br></br>
  <Button ID="buttonLogout" style="widht:60px; height:50px;" Class="ButtonAction"
      onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"
      onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" runat="server">Logout
   </Button>


<textarea ID="txtNpersonas" style="font-size:25px; width:150px;"   runat="server">4</textarea>
```

Comment: Si perfecto gracias.

Comment: Hola, una pregunta en la variable var valor=0; para pasarle el valor del campo de texto actual como sería he probado con: var valor = $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val(); en vez de aumentarme, me coloca 1111..

Comment: Para qué quieres asignar `var valor = $("[id$=txtNpersonas]").val()` si el conteo lo hace por fuera?

Comment: en mi sistema cuando realizo otra acción pierde ese valor, empieza de nuevo a contar desde cero. Por ejemplo: tengo en mi caja de texto un 4 realizo otra accion o actualizo el valor se mantiene pero en el contador empieza de nuevo a contar desde 0. Adjunto foto para más información

Comment: pues mucho no te puedo ayudar, necesito que actualices la pregunta con el código de cuando "realizas otra acción" para poder saber cual es el error.

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta para mas detalle.

Comment: Y yo mi respuesta, espero te sirva.

Comment: Si perfecto me ha servido. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo lo que quieres es que un botón incremente y otro haga una disminución en un solo input. Esto puede servirte:

```js
function Action(increment){
    const input = document.getElementById("myInput")

    if (increment) 
        input.value = parseFloat(input.value) + 1
    else
        input.value = parseFloat(input.value) - 1
}
```

```html
 <input id="myInput" type="number" value="0">
 <button id="btnIncrement" onclick="Action(true)">Incrementar</button>
 <button id="btnDecrement" onclick="Action(false)">Disminuir</button>
```